# Output from executing 'busybox top' in Android app run-time differs from shell output

Tags: java, android, busybox, top-command

I am trying to create a system application for Android to display the top entries when running `busybox top -n 1` command. I implemented this by defining a process in my application:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/sh", "-c" "busybox top -n 1");
```

and then reading from binding the `stdout` to a buffered `InputStream`

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("output",line);
}
```

While I have manged to receive an output from running this, it appears that the processes the application lists are only those that are spawned from the application itself, which differs from the output of directly executing `busybox top -n 1` using `adb shell`. What can I do to make my application see all running system processes?